# Android error: package android.* does not exist > import android.os.Bundle;

Tags: java, android, android-studio

since I changed my project java version in build.gradle from 1_8 to 11 this error appears, do you know how can I repair it, and I really need this java version, so thanks in advance for your answear.

Comment: You should `Invalidate caches and restart` Android Studio from Menu bar. Once restarted, try syncing Project with gradle files - the elephant icon.

Answer (score 0):

Your Android Gradle Plugin might need to be upgraded to 7.

When you start Android Studio, check the notification in the bottom-right corner that says "Project Update recommended, Android Gradle Plugin can be updated." like the picture below.
[image]

Hit that blue 'updated' text to start upgrading it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to download the new update if you don't have it.

If you can't find the notification like @DuncanSungWKim says, you can go to Settings > Plugins > Gradle Plugin and you would find the update button.

If after the update it still doesn't work, try changing the Java version from 11 to 1.11 since that happened to me.

I hope this will work for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).